# Coldfusion2018 installer fails on Ubuntu 20.04.2 ARM64

Tags: 20.04, macbook-pro, arm64

I am trying to install Coldfusion server on my Ubuntu 20.04  (running on virtual machine in Parallels Desktop for Mac). Ubuntu is running as a Guest operating system on my MacbookPro with M1Pro chip.

I have downloaded the Coldfusion2018Linux64 binary, and when i try to install it, it complains about JRE libraries either missing or incompatible and the installer exits. Please look at the log below:

```
Preparing to install
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

JRE libraries are missing or not compatible....
Exiting....
```

Coldfusion server configuration comes with an embedded JEE server, so I am confused what is going on..
Any ideas what needs to be done to resolve this issue and install coldfusion successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It must be that the binary was made for amd64. Ask the developers for an arm64 version.

Comment: Or you don't have the Java Runtime Environment installed which is *exactly* what the error message suggests. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-jre#1-overview